# How can I test for a URLs existeance before redirecting to it?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mobile-devices, useragent

I am using Apache's mod_rewrite to redirect mobile users to my mobile site based on their http_user_agent. However not all pages have a mobile equivalent. Also mobile pages end in .html and "full" pages end in .shtml.

Here is some pseudo code.

Does the user have a certain HTTP_USER_AGENT?

Is there a mobile page?

If so take them there. If not, no redirection is needed.

Answer (score 2):

[RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) allows backreferences[0] to capture groups in the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobile
RewriteCond $1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.shtml$ $1.html [R]
```

[0] More like a forward reference actually...

Answer (score 0):

Probably best post this in webmasters section. But you want something like the following i presume?

```
<script language=javascript>

<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html");
}
-->
</script>
```

There are loads of site to assist you in this - http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

Just simply add the script to the pages you want detection on, there is no need to pre-check for a site page existence.

Comment: Ok I can try there - I want to do this with apache and not javascript

Comment: This is what you need in that case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Comment: That helps but it does not test for the existence of a file before redirecting there.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can use php to do this, then you could do;

```
<?php
$THEPAGE = 'WHATEVER THE URL YOU WANT IT TO BE';
$page = file_get_contents("$THEPAGE");
if(strstr($page, '404'))
{
}
else
{
header('Location: ' .$THEPAGE .'\')';
}
?>
```

Comment: Needs to be apache